# Difference between passing &:method and :method as function arguments in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, function-pointers, symbols

I'm struggling in understanding when to use the ampersand in passing symbols to functions representing a method. For example, If I wanted to calculate the sum of the range 1..10, I could do the following:

`(1..10).inject(:+)`

This originally lead me to believe that if you wanted to pass a symbol to define a method to "Magically" be used in the function, you would pass the function name as a symbol. But then I see something like this in rails:

`total = Product.find(product_list).sum(&:price)`

If I understand correctly, &:price is the same as calling :price.to_proc. I don't understand how the above works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Enumerable#Inject, I just used that as an example.

Comment: The effect of `:+` tightly depends on `inject` in your example while `&:price` does not.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In actual parameter list of a method call, `&object` is built-in syntax, which will

1. convert `object` to a Proc using `object.to_proc`
2. pass the Proc as the block parameter of the method

`Symbol#to_proc` converts the symbol (eg. :the_symbol) to `proc {|obj| obj.send(:the_symbol)}`. And you can use this syntax whenever `object` responds to `to_proc` method and returns a Proc.

```rb
abc = "aha~"
class << abc
  def to_proc
    proc {|obj| obj.to_i * 2 }
  end
end
p ["1", "2", "3"].map(&abc)
#=> [2, 4, 6]
```

`(1..10).inject(:+)` shows that inject accepts a symbol as parameter. How the symbol is used is method specific behavior. In `inject`'s special case, it has the same effect as `(1..10).inject{|a, b| a.send(:+, b)}`. It's just a simple, normal parameter, the effect depends on the implementation of the method that accept the symbol as parameter.

Note that `sum` in ActiveSupport accepts a block with single parameter, which has the effect "**map values in the original sequence to new ones and calculate the sum of them**", so

```rb
total = Product.find(product_list).sum(&:price)
```

is equivalent as

```rb
total = Product.find(product_list).sum(&proc{|p| p.send(:price)})
# or you may write
total = Product.find(product_list).sum{|p| p.price }
```

which has the same return value as the following but won't produce intermediate temp array:

```rb
total = Product.find(product_list).map{|p| p.price}.sum
```

Comment: I thought & is shorthand for to_proc, not to_sym, am I wrong?

Comment: How does :price.to_proc interact with sum? I mean, I'd assume that this somehow gets converted to product.price, and sums those prices.